# Github - Store Html/CSS file without change langage stats

Tags: github, github-linguist

I made a small scraper in **Crystal** hosted on **Github**. I want to store website **HTML** for testing purposes but when I do my Github project appear as written in Html *(because of quantity of **HTML** compared to quantity of Crystal lines)*.

How can I *"ignore"* theses Html files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded that HTML/CCS files stored in `doc/` or `docs/` folder at the root of your project will not impact repository language stats.

Answer (score 2):

The open source [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides) project is in charge of computing language statistics for repositories. You can use [**Linguist overrides**](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides) to change its detection output.

In particular, you might want to add the following lines in your `.gitattributes` file:

```
*.html linguist-vendored
*.css linguist-vendored
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can control what language github recognize your project as.

You can definitely ignore the html files by using `.gitignore` (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), but you will be literally ignoring those files and they will not appear in your github repository.

Comment: Yes but I want to use theses files for units test so I can't ignore them...